# Framer Motion Page Transition with React Router DOM v6 causes rerender of layout components (esp. Sidebar) on Page Change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I recently added page transition to my React app using the library Framer Motion and React-Router-DOM. However, all layout components such as sidebar, navbar, etc. have been experiencing unwanted rerenders upon page change. Below is the snippet for my router and layout:

Router:

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait">
   <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
      <Route element={<GuestMiddleware />}>
         // Routes without layout
      </Route>

      <Route element={<AuthMiddleware />}>
         <Route element={<AdminLayout />}>   // <-- Here is the Layout
            // Routes with layout         
         </Route>
      </Route>
   </Routes>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Layout:

```
<>
   <Sidebar />

   <div className={cn("transition-spacing flex min-h-d-screen w-full flex-col ps-0 duration-300", { "lg:ps-sidebar": isOpen })}>
      <Topbar />

      <div className="grow">
         <Outlet />
      </div>
   </div>
</>
```

I actually found the reason for rerenders being the key attribute in the `Routes` component. But then once I remove it, all page exit transitions tend to behave incorrectly. I want to know if there is a way to fix or even a possible workaround regarding this.

Comment: This seems to ***not*** be ***unexpected*** behavior, when a React component renders it renders its entire sub-ReactTree. Is there an issue or problem with some more deeply nested components rerendering?

Comment: The sidebar contains an image that is lazy loaded, therefore everytime the component rerenders (on page change), the blur animation caused by lazy loading happens as well.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the image is lazy loaded more than once, e.g. the initial load? It shouldn't need to be loaded more than one time. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: I have made a devbox which reproduces the aforementioned scenario... Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/cool-resonance-8djwq6?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FSidebar.tsx%3A21%2C74. I wanted to add that this also affects the accordions defined inside the sidebar... since the accordions closes on page change due to rerender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that the `Sidebar` component is rendered by the `Layout` component within the `Routes` using the current `location.pathname` as a React key. When the key changes, e.g. when the route location changes, the `Routes` component is remounted, including its entire sub-ReactTree.

The solution is to move `Sidebar` ***out*** of the `AnimatedPresence` so it's not remounted when animating the route transitions.

Layout.tsx

Remove `Sidebar` from the `Layout` component.

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Topbar from "../components/Topbar";
import { cn } from "../utils/cn";
import { useSidebarStore } from "../features/stores/sidebar";

const Layout = () => {
  const { isOpen } = useSidebarStore();

  return (
    <main
      className={cn(
        "transition-[padding] duration-300 relative flex flex-col w-full min-h-screen",
        isOpen ? "ps-[300px]" : "ps-0",
      )}
    >
      <Topbar />

      <div className="grow">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

router.tsx

Render `Sidebar` in the `Router` outside `AnimatePresence`.

```
import { useLocation, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

import Layout from "./layouts/Layout";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Preferences from "./pages/settings/Preferences";
import Users from "./pages/settings/Users";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";

const Router = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        <Routes {...{ location, key: location.pathname }}>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="settings">
              <Route path="preferences" element={<Preferences />} />
              <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: The thing is I have pages which does not extend from the layout, e.g. Login Page... so if I put the layout outside the Route definitions... the layout would also appear in those pages unless I explicitly define conditional rendering based on current pathname. You may refer on the orig post for the structure of the routes.

Comment: @alas.code So the `SideBar` should render with *only* the `AdminLayout` route's routes? There is only 1 layout route in the sandbox demo you provided. Can you update the sandbox to more accurately reflect your use case? You may just need to apply some conditional rendering.

Comment: Yes the sidebar should render on routes under the AdminLayout. I have updated the sandbox, that includes authentication simulation since the login page does not extend on the admin layout. https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/thirsty-goodall-8nhqc4?file=%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Fauth%2FLogin.tsx%3A15%2C17

Comment: @alas.code The solutions I see are you moving the `Sidebar` component out of the `AnimatedPresence` and you conditionally render it based on location, ***or*** you create separate routing components that render descendent routes such that `Layout` renders it's own `AnimatedPresence` and descendent routes with `Sidebar` outside and `Login` as a descendent route in its own route component with its own `AnimatedPresence` ***or*** you find a different component than `LazyLoadImage` to render the user avatar or don't apply the loading effect to it.

Comment: Ok I get it... thanks sir!